# Use AJAX request to get an Array and use inside JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I'm working on a live update chart, and for that, I made a separate file with the data I need. I made a request on my main page with AJAX so I could get the Array into the main page. But for some reason, I can't use this array outside the request. I would need to use this arrays inside the  part only. 
Here's what I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON("loadchart.php", function(data){
          var sensor1 = data[0];
          var sensor2 = data[1];
          var sensor3 = data[2];
          var sensorsum = data[3];
      });
    });
    console.log(sensor1);

    //My chart stuff down here
```

When I try to console log of the array it gives an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sensor1 is not defined
    at main.php:107
```

This is the new function I tried:

```
async () => {
      async function foo() {
        return $.ajax({
          url: "loadchart.php",
          success: function(data){
            return data;
          }
        });
      }

    var result = await foo();

    console.log(result);
    };
```

Comment: Your error is coming from scope issues btw, but the main problem is the link above.

Comment: You can not read variable 'sensor1' because this variable is declared later in the scope because ajax response is async and called after reading that variable. Check  @ASDFGerte posted link.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Isn't a easier solution for only taking it out of the AJAX request?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I would have to change my $.getJSON?

Comment: @Matheus here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21e4kh7t/90/) with some examples of deferred objects using jquery, Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why sensor1 is undefined.

One reason is that you declare the variable in a lower scope. You can't access a variable that was declared in your callback function outside that callback function.

The second reason is because a callback function gets called after a response is given from the api that you are calling. However, you are trying to access the variable right away when the script runs. This won't work because you need the variable to be defined first.

The solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("loadchart.php", function(data){
         var sensor1 = data[0];
         var sensor2 = data[1]; 
         var sensor3 = data[2]; 
         var sensorsum = data[3];

         //move the console.log into this scope.
         console.log(sensor1);
     }); 
});
```

Keep in mind, the `console.log()` will only work if:

The request is successful

The returned data has the same data structure as you are using.

Comment: That's not what I need, I need to use the sensor1 out of the AJAX request

Comment: Yes. So instead of doing console.log Just use sensor1

Comment: Sensor1 doesn't work out of the AJAX request...